# utf-8 encode dictionary key-values if type is string

Tags: python

Given a dictionary, how to encode utf-8 dictionary key-values if only type is string? For example, using dictionary comprehension:

```
{k.encode("utf-8"): v.encode("utf-8") for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

Given: `mydict = {u'foo': u'bar', u'red': u'color', u'size': 12}`, encode dictionary key-value such that it becomes `mydict = {'foo': 'bar', 'red': 'color', 'size': 12}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditionals:

```
{
    k.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(k, unicode) else k: 
    v.encode("utf-8") if isinstance(v, unicode) else v
    for k, v in mydict.iteritems()
}
```

Or a helper function:

```
def conditional_encode(s, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        return s.encode(encoding, errors)
    return s

{conditional_encode(k): conditional_encode(v) for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming keys are always strings, just check if the type of the value is string

```
{k.encode("utf-8"): v.encode("utf-8") if type(v) is str else v 
 for k, v in mydict.iteritems()}
```